# Magento ORM Documentation

Tags: php, django, orm, magento, entity-attribute-value

Outside of the source code, is there any extensive documentation on the Magento ORM?  I get the basics, and can usually dig through the Mage code base, litter it with Mage::Log calls and figure out something that works, but my efficiency would go way up if I had a high level overview of how the models are **intended** to be used.  How do the aggregate methods work, what's the best way to join, when should you extend the models, when's the best time to use the eav models vs. the non-eav ones, etc.

Something like the [Django Model Documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/), but for Magento.

Comment: Id love to hear an answer for this too. The documentation for Magento is sorely lacking.

Comment: For anyone looking, I ended up partially solving this problem myself. http://alanstorm.com/category/magento

Comment: Hi Alan, your resources have been invaluable. I have another question that I think you might know the answer too, and in addition would be a good resource for other novice magento devs such as myself. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356138/need-documentation-for-magento-models-magegetmodel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this question was answered, some documentation has been created on the ORM at the magento knowledge base.

Introductory information: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-5-magento-models-and-orm-basics

Advanced ORM usage and the EAV system: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-7-advanced-orm-entity-attribute-value

Working with the Varien collections (lazy loading, filtering, etc...): http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-8-varien-data-collections

Comment: And, ironically from a certain point of view, I'm the one who wrote those articles AND asked this question.

Comment: Alan, that's hilarious - I didn't notice it was you who'd asked the question. I've read a lot of the magento articles you've written, they're fantastic, well done!

Comment: Sadly all of those links are now dead.

Answer (score 4):

While there isn't much documentation on the ORM, here were a few pages that greatly helped in my understanding of the database structure which will help you understand everything else:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/development/magento_database_diagram
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/7359/

Answer (score 3):

For the Magento ORM which is based off of Zend Framework's Zend_Db_Adapter , you can use the Zend Framework Programmers Reference (Available as a free pdf on [Zend Framework's site](http://framework.zend.com/) ). I also found this [link](http://activecodeline.com/getting-things-in-magento-by-getmodel-and-getdata-methods/) helpful for learning more about Magento models.

Comment: Good info, but not quite what I'm looking for. Magento uses Zend_Db_Adapter to make all its database calls, but the actual ORM (mapping database table to objects) inherits from the core Varian Object.  The ORM **uses** Zend_Db_Adapter to talk to databases.  I'm interested in documentation of the ORM itself (if it exists and if doesn't vary wildly between Models)