# Need documentation for Magento Models (Mage::getModel())

Tags: magento, orm

I've read Alan Storm's guide [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-5-magento-models-and-orm-basics) on Magento ORM principles and how to access the data. I'm writing a plugin to export data from magento.

**Question**

Where do I find documentation for the different types of models available in Magento?

For example,

`Mage::getModel("catalog/categories");`

What are the other allowable models in getModel?.

There's some information in the API documentation, like product.list, and if I were to guess, then I would say that this some how translates over to the getModel call, but i'm not sure how. Can anyone link me? google searches for "getModel documentation" and 
"Magento models" produce no relevant results.

Here are the links I have looked at:

1. [DB Diagram](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/2_-_magento_concepts_and_architecture/magento_database_diagram)
2. [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773562/magento-orm-documentation)
3. [getModel and getData methods](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-debugging/getting-things-in-magento-by-getmodel-and-getdata-methods/)
4. [Alan Storm's guide](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento)

So far, Alan's stuff has been the most helpful.
Help me, @Alan Storm :)

Comment: is it for a learning purpose ? cause magento already got few export tools...

Comment: I have a custom use for the export tool. i'm currently reading through the other tools like: Lexity Shopping Feeds 
Payserv_Pricero
Shopalize's Live Activity Feed Discovery
Shopping Flux - Feed Management Software
NextPromote
Smart Buy

ConnectgentoShopbotFeed
GoDataFeed

EM RSS/Atom News Feed Widget
News by CommerceLab

Miura Promotion RSS feed
Flagbit Feed Reader

Comment: this my answers on these topics, it could help : http://stackoverflow.com/a/13203197/1112003 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/12937989/1112003

Comment: "I've been Alan Storm's guide"? You must be a magento's core developer team member then ;)

Comment: thanks for that, i've made an update

Answer (score 2):

You should dig into code. Using `getModel` you're able to get an instance of each class of each module which is located in `Models` directories. In `catalog/product_option_a_b_c` expression, the fitst part (`catalog`) references to module and the second part references to `Product/Option/A/B/C.php` file in the `Models` directory of `catalog` module. So if you want to get an instance of `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address` class, you need this: `Mage::getModel('sales/quote_address')`

Comment: this the best voted answer but no answer to the question "Where do I find documentation" - does this mean there is no real API documentation for the biggest shopsystem? O.o

Comment: @MartinEckleben there's no documentation for each class and method of Magento

Answer (score 0):

you probably know that magento is comprised of several MVC modules so according to its standard each module has a Model directory. getModel() uses this structure to find which model you want to load. basically the call is in this format:

> module/path_to_the_name_of_model_including_the_model_file_name

remember not to include model directory and use underscore to separate directories. also the name of the directories are in lowercase however in reality they start with uppercase.